# Filtering a Flow by a Date Field Calculation using SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I am working on a Flow for a Training Tracking system I am making in PowerApps. The users requested that I setup an automated email to send info about Expired training on a weekly basis.

I have the value of "TrainingLog_ExpiryDate" on my list, which is calculated on the app and saved to the list as a Date field with Time not selected.

I want the flow to filter the "Get Items" with basically: If utcNow() is past the TrainingLog_ExpiryDate, add it to a table.

I am aware that flows require "formatDateTime" to ensure the comparison works but I for the life of me cannot get it working. I currently have the import from sharepoint as
`formatDateTime('TrainingLog_ExpiryDate', 'dd, MM, yyyy')`
And have tried comparing this to a similarly formatted one for utcNow() but it errored saying the two fields are not comparible.

Could anyone help me wrap my head around how I would go about sorting this?